# Which ports to forward for a VPN server that sits behind a firewall?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, vpn

Question pretty much says it all.

From what I have found, it seems that port 1723 is the main port to forward, but I also see numerous references to others ports.

The server that is hosting the VPN is a Windows 2008 Server.

Answer (score 5):

What protocol is the VPN server using, PPTP, L2TP, IPSEC?

- PPTP uses TCP port 1723 and protocol 47
- L2TP uses UDP port 1701
- IPSEC uses UDP port 500 and protocols 50 and 51

Comment: Also OpenVPN uses 1194 by default. And remember that not all operate over TCP - UDP is more common.

Comment: To clarify a bit...  IPSec uses UDP 500 (and possibly UDP 4500 if behind a NAT) along with Protocol 50 and 51 instead of ports.

Comment: Important missing detail is the fact the PPTP uses 1723/TCP, and L2TP uses 1701/UDP. Not sure where you got port 47 from! Sure you aren't thinking of Protocol 47?

Comment: I meant to say protocol instead of port. My bad. Sorry.

Comment: maybe edit you post then?

Comment: If I would have caught it I would have. since someone else caught it I didn't see any point in editing my post since they corrected me. Did you get confused by it? Sorry.

Comment: Don't forget SSL VPN's, TCP port 443.  The question itself should be reworded as "Which ports to forward for a (insert type here) VPN server that sits behind a firewall?" once the OP explains